# Matlab Image Blob Detection Using Recursive Flood Fill

Tags: matlab, recursion, image-processing, computer-vision, flood-fill

I am trying to do blob detection in Matlab. How can I get rid of my infinite recursion in flood_fill().

```
%Input Image
blobs = im2bw(imread('Week6Image.jpg'),0.1);

disp(blobs);

[W, H] = size(blobs);

region_labeling(blobs,W,H)



function region_labeling(I,W,H)

label = 2;

for u = 1 : W
    %For loop vertical Axis
    for v = 1 : H
        if I(u,v) == 1
            flood_fill(I,u,v,label,W,H);
            label = label + 1;
        end
    end

end

end
```

It gets stuck in this function due to infinite recursion. What should I do so that it breaks out at the right time.

```
function flood_fill(I,u,v,label,W,H)

if u >= 1 && u < W && v >= 1 && v < H && I(u,v) == 1
    I(u,v) = label;
    flood_fill(I,u+1,v,label,W,H);
    flood_fill(I,u,v+1,label,W,H);
    flood_fill(I,u,v-1,label,W,H);
    flood_fill(I,u-1,v,label,W,H);


end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that is an infinite recursion. But it must be terribly slow, maybe it just takes such a long time you think it is stuck in an infinite recursion?

Comment: But note that test should be `u <= W` and `v <= H`, otherwise you won't fill the last row and the last column of the image.

Comment: I will modify the test. As far as the recursion goes. Matlab throws an infinite recursion error. Is there a setting for recursion depth in Matlab?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think it is typically capped at a fairly low value. I would really suggest a better algorithm over tweaking the recursion limit. But you can change it with `set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)`.

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem now: you are passing `I` into the function, but not getting the modifications back. MATLAB passes all arguments by value (with the exception of handle classes). This means that a function can change its input arguments without changing the value of those matrices in the caller's workspace. You need to modify the `flood_fill` function to return `I`.

The other issue is that `blobs` is a logical array, and assigning any non-zero value to it yields a value of 1. You need to cast it to some other type, either doubles with `+blobs` or a specific integer type as below.

This is the corrected code:

```
blobs = im2bw(imread('Week6Image.jpg'),0.1);
blobs = uint16(blobs); % or uint32 if you have many regions
[W, H] = size(blobs);
out = region_labeling(blobs,W,H);

function I = region_labeling(I,W,H)
label = 2;
for u = 1 : W
   %For loop vertical Axis
   for v = 1 : H
      if I(u,v) == 1
         I = flood_fill(I,u,v,label,W,H);
         label = label + 1;
      end
   end
end
end

function I = flood_fill(I,u,v,label,W,H)
if u >= 1 && u <= W && v >= 1 && v <= H && I(u,v) == 1
   I(u,v) = label;
   I = flood_fill(I,u+1,v,label,W,H);
   I = flood_fill(I,u,v+1,label,W,H);
   I = flood_fill(I,u,v-1,label,W,H);
   I = flood_fill(I,u-1,v,label,W,H);
end
end
```

Note also that it is beneficial, in a double loop, to have the fastest-changing index be the inner loop. MATLAB is column-major, so in `I(u,v)`, `u` is the fastest-changing index. Thus, ideally you would swap the two for loops around. But, given that this is such a slow algorithm and that MATLAB is not so efficient with recursion, you will likely not see the difference in this particular piece of code.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I am still having issues. My input image is only 20x15 pixels, I set the recursion depth limit to 100,000 and it still just sits there.  Do you think there may be something wrong with my test?

Comment: @BrentVaalburg: You shouldn’t need to change your recursion limit. This code  as posted here worked for me, but it is slow.

Comment: Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.

Error in blob_detection>flood_fill (line 22)
   I = flood_fill(I,u+1,v,label,W,H);

Comment: @BrentVaalburg: Are you using the code exactly as I posted here? With an image with 300 pixels? That cannot throw an out of memory error. I don’t see how that could happen. Could you try it with `blobs=ones(15,20)`?

Comment: That worked, maybe the pattern in my image is throwing it into a weird loop somehow?

Comment: @BrentVaalburg: Maybe your image is a logical array? That would convert any positive value to 1, and thus stick you in an infinite loop. Sorry I didn’t think of this earlier! See the edit.